# Общий файл подкачки

Tags: windows, файлы, память

Представим две Windows-системы (например, Win7 и Win10), установленные на разные разделы. Хорошая ли идея на отдельном разделе выделить им общий файл подкачки?

Кстати, какую файловую систему лучше при этом использовать (а то возникло подозрение, что у разных систем могут оказаться разные права на него)?

Comment: Был неправ, удалил ответ. Это я похоже что-то намудрил с конфигурацией, что у второй системы файл подкачки не вижу. Сейчас перегрузился на вторую систему, и у рабочей файл подкачки остался на месте.

Comment: @freim, ну вообще явно настроить удаление при выключении - вроде тоже вариант, впрочем, при аварийном выключении файл всё равно будет оставаться.

Comment: Не помню времена, когда 2 винды рядом - было хорошей идеей. А учитывая, как 10 любит хозяйничать с разделами и загрузчиками - я бы миллион раз подумал

Comment: @donRumata, что-то не понял, к чему "не" относится.

Comment: @don Rumata  Вин10 с разделами хозяйничает? И две винды рядом можно использовать во время переходного режима или когда одна винда может некие программы запускать, а другая уже отказывается. Комплект ХР+7 очень часто встречается.

Comment: @Adokenai, https://juick.com/don-Rumata/2841849. В 2k19 ничего не поменялось. Если бить разделы руками "под себя" - даже свежая десятка сделает минимум один.

Comment: @don Rumata может я невнимательный, но где по ссылке упоминаются разделы? Про загрузчик я не спрашивал. И появился дополнительный вопрос: какой резон писать 2к19 вместо 2019? В 200х это было актуально, т.к. сокращало запись на целый символ, что актуально на всяких Twitter, в СМС и ином, где считался каждый символ.

Comment: @Adokenai, ну тогдашний разбор полётов показал, что и с разделами не всё гладко. Не только загрузчик затронуло. "какой резон писать 2к19" - это просто отсылка к "мемам" современных интернетов - не более.

Answer (score 1):

Раздел подкачки используется во время работы. При перезагрузке в другую ОС, данные меняются. Поэтому ничего плохого. Для безопасности можно включить очистку перед завершением.

Вопрос прав решается их настройкой.

А в идеале, виртуальную память нужно отключать. Если объём памяти позволяет.